# Can the Windows clock be configured to display a 24-hour-based time?

Tags: windows, display, time, clock

Is it possible to make the windows clock display its time in a 24-hour format instead of the default 12-hour format? There doesn't appear to be any way to do this via the UI, but I'm wondering if maybe there's a registry setting somewhere I don't know about.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the alleged 12-hour default format is locale-dependent. Most countries (and hence locales) nowadays use 24-hour clocks by default.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you can. It's not on the Time control panel, it's on the Regional Options. You'll have to make a custom region that uses 24h time. The time format should be "H:mm:ss" instead of "h:mm:ss".

Answer (score 3):

With Windows 10 it's a bit different, you can go to the time settings via clicking on the clock, then into date & time formats. Once you've done that you can change the formats to HH:mm (uppercase important) under short & long. It's a new menu and a bit easier to get into, but similar to older versions of Windows as per the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on clock in System tray, in the box that opens click on Region and Language, then at bottom open Additional Date and Time Settings under heading Regional Settings.  OR open Control Panel and navigate to Clock, Language and Region
Next open  Change Date, Time or Number formats
Click on arrow at end of Short Time format (h:mm) and select option HH:mm
Click on arrow at end of Long Time (h:mm:ss) and select option HH:mm;ss
Click on Apply and close Control Panel

Comment: Which version of Windows is this for?