# Can I set my computer's clock display to 24-hour format?

Tags: windows-7, time, date-time, clock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the Windows clock be configured to display a 24-hour-based time?](https://superuser.com/questions/153787/can-the-windows-clock-be-configured-to-display-a-24-hour-based-time)

The title pretty much says it here.  I'm just wondering, is it possible to switch my Windows 7 computer's clock display format from the default 12-Hour, to 24-Hour?  If so, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: The computer's clock is already 24-hour. Did you mean the clock display in the system tray?

Comment: Flagging as a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/153787/can-the-windows-clock-be-configured-to-display-a-24-hour-based-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click Start, then type "intl.cpl" into the Search box and hit Enter. That will display the Region and Language control panel, where you can select military time for Windows.