# How do I change time format in Windows 10 Windows Update scheduler?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, date-time, text-formatting

My Date & time format are set correctly as far as I can surmise, I live in Finland, but prefer English as my OS language, yet, parts of Windows 10 UI seem to follow the 10PM/AM style instead of 24hr clock.

Any ideas how to get the time format displayed as expected?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try the answer [from here?](http://superuser.com/questions/153787/can-the-windows-clock-be-configured-to-display-a-24-hour-based-time)

Comment: Click on "Change data and time formats". Change `hh` to `HH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change these settings in the PC settings section:

[image]

[image]

1. In date formats, the meaning of the notifications is as follows.

> d, dd=day; dddd=day of week; M=month; y=year.

2. In time formats, the meaning of the notifications is as below.

> h=hour; m=minute; s=second; tt=AM or PM; h/H=12/24 hours; hh, mm,
>   ss=display leading zero; h, m, s=do not display leading zero.

Comment: For me, the dropdowns contain only one setting (the currently active one). Wish we could input our own preference. My task bar clock is in 24hr format, as are Explorer file modified\created times, the only place where I'm seeing AM/PM is Windows update dialog.

Comment: Some settings can be controlled by group policy, is the machine in a domain?

Comment: Nope, a home PC that I upgraded to Win 10 from Win 7 in the spring. I'll test if I get more options if I install more languages.

Comment: Ok! Let me know the outcome of the test.

Comment: Will do this evening, at work now. :)